# Remove all lines except matching pattern line best practice (sed)

Tags: unix, sed

I want to remove all lines except the line(s) containing matching pattern.

This is how I did it:

```
sed -n 's/matchingpattern/matchingpattern/p' file.txt
```

But I'm just curious because I rename matching pattern to the matching pattern itself. Looks like a waste here.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
sed '/pattern/!d' file.txt
```

But you're reinventing `grep` here.

Comment: Yup. But sed has this nifty --in-place flag that grep does not have.
sed -i '/pattern/!d' filename
is much easier than
grep 'pattern' filename > filename.tmp && mv filename.tmp filename

Comment: Warning: I supplied the --quiet flag to avoid any results to be printed to the terminal, not realizing -i already achieves that in itself. This meant that all lines were deleted, even those matching the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

grep is certainly better...because it's much faster.

e.g. using grep to extract all genome sequence data for chromosome 6 in a data set I'm working with:

```
$ time grep chr6 seq_file.in > temp.out

real    0m11.902s
user    0m9.564s
sys 0m1.912s
```

compared to sed:

```
$ time sed '/chr6/!d' seq_file.in > temp.out

real    0m21.217s
user    0m18.920s
sys 0m1.860s
```

I repeated it 3X and ~same values each time.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/matchingpattern/p' file.txt
```

`/.../` is an address which may have actions attached in this case `p`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using sed, which is complicated, use grep.

```
grep matching_pattern file
```

This should give you the desired result.

Comment: +1 for the 'right tool.'  but sed can modify a file in place.