# delete lines in file not matching the pattern

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to migrate data which consists of a lot of separate text files. One step is to delete all lines in the text files, which are not used anymore. The lines are key-value-pairs. I want to delete everything in a file except those lines with certain keys. I do not know the order of the keys inside of the file.

The keys I want to keep are e.g. version, date and number.

I found this question [Remove all lines except matching pattern line best practice (sed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922706/remove-all-lines-except-matching-pattern-line-best-practice-sed) and tried the accepted answer. My sed command is

```
sed '/^(version=.*$)|(date=.*$)|(number=.*$)/!d' file.txt
```

with a !d after the address to delete all lines NOT matching the pattern.

Example of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/LKfxpP/2

but it keeps deleting all lines in my file. Where is my mistake? I assume I am wrong with my regex, but whats the error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed '/^\(version\|date\|number\)=/!d' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

The BRE POSIX pattern here matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `\(version\|date\|number\)` - a group matching

  - `version` - a `version` string
  - `\|` - or
  - `date` - a `date` string
  - `\|` - or
  - `number`  - a `number` string
- `=` - a `=` char.

Or, use a POSIX ERE syntax enabled with `-E` option:

```
sed -E '/^(version|date|number)=/!d' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Here, the alternation operator `|` and capturing parentheses do not need escaping.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/XokaF5).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The different kinds of pattern are the part I was missing. The POSIX ERE syntax is exactly what I can use in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F= '$1 !~ /version|date|number/' file.txt
```

The field separator is set to `=` and the first field must not match the given string.